# Docker Network: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED using FETCH API

Tags: docker, api, containers

Something weird is happening. I have this docker structure:

```
 +------------------------+       +-------------------------+
 |                        |       |                         |
 |                        |       |                         |
 |   api_application      |       |                         |
 |                        |       |   web_application       |
 |                        |       |                         |
 |                        |       |                         |
 |                        |       |                         |
 +------------------------+       +-------------------------+
                    |                      |
                    |                      |
                    |                      |
                    |                      |
                    +----------------------+
                               |
                               +
                         application_br
```

`web_application - express.js`
`api_application - Flask`

I make use of Fetch API in search.html and app.js, that last use node_fetch.

app.js example:

```
  (async () => {
    const body = req.body;
  
    const response = await fetch('http://api_application:5000/auth', {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    if(typeof(json)=="object"){
      req.session.nome = json[0];
      console.log("Logged");
      res.redirect("/");
    }else if(typeof(json)=="string"){
        //Usuario Incorreto
        console.log("Failed");
        res.redirect('login');
    }
  })();
```

search.html:

```
<script>
fetch('http://api_application:5000/search/12345')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
</script>
```

The Node_Fetch works fine, instead Fetch API (Javascript) I receive this error:

> search:114 GET http://api_application:5000/search/52365
> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Thats not make sense, because if I exec bash in `web_application` and execute `curl http://api_application:5000/search/1233` I got the json response.

Ping between Containers - fine
Curl API from Web Container - fine

Is there some problem in Fetch API? Where am I wrong?

Comment: The `search.html` contents runs in the _browser_; that's outside of Docker and can't use any of Docker's networking features (including calling containers by name).

Comment: I should create the same function using node_fetch right?